# Reinstantiation issue using Inter App Communication with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, communication

I am developing an WP8 app that uses a webbrowser control that shows statefull server content. On WP8 you can switch between apps manually. E.g. if you want to copy&paste some information from one app into a browser input field. If you switch that way, the current app instance stays alive. That means the web session and the current page of the browser control will stay available.

Now I want another app to send some data directly into the app with the browser control - without restarting it...

From what I know, there are three ways to handle inter app communication:

1. register a file type that will open the app by launching that file from local storage
2. register an app protocol and use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() to submit parameters in a query string
3. use a shared storage file

Detailed information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

I think the last approach is not usefull, because after you have started the second app, there is now way to activate the calling app **or is there any usefull way to reactivate the webbrowser app**?

I tried the second approach, but I am running in an issue, because it starts a new instance by design. That means InitializePhoneApplication is called. There is the entry point for the custom UriMapper that reads the incoming parameters. So **the old app instance is killed and all session data, cookies and input fields are gone**. With WP webbrowser control you are not able to store the cookie and page state, so a fast app resume is not possible also.

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    if (this.phoneApplicationInitialized)
    {
        return;
    }

    RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
    RootFrame.Navigated += this.CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

    RootFrame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper();

    //...
    this.phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
}
```

**Is there any other way or a possibility to use the shown approaches to send data between apps without restarting them using LanchUri()?**

That means, to send some data back to a running instance without reinitializing the whole app, so that the page state and session state are still available on the target app.

Best regards

Holger

Answer (score 0):

FastAppResume is the solution. I haven't used it and thought it also reinitiates the app. But it doesnt. This [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Fast-app-resume-backstack-f16baaa6) shows how to reuse the existing instance.

Regards
Holger